# How does goroutine schedule work with GOMAXPROCS?

Tags: go, goroutine

I am so confused by **goroutines**.

Here is the code

```golang
func main() {
    // runtime.GOMAXPROCS(1)
    go spinner(100 * time.Millisecond)
    const n = 45
    fibN := fib(n) // slow
    fmt.Printf("\rFibonacci(%d) = %d\n", n, fibN)
}

func spinner(delay time.Duration) {
    for {
        for _, r := range `-\|/` {
            fmt.Printf("\r%c", r)
            time.Sleep(delay)
        }
    }
}

func fib(x int) int {
    if x < 2 {
        return x
    }
    return fib(x-1) + fib(x-2)
}
```

That is a simple **goroutine** tutorial code which using goroutine to *show an ASCII animation* when calculating *Fibonacci*.

When I set `GOMAXPROCS` to `1`, I think that there will be only one thread to execute goroutine and the Fibonacci function doesn't have any point to yield to animation goroutine. But this demo still works. It shows animation while doing calculating.

How does Go do this without goroutine switching?

Comment: Goroutines are multiplexed on OS threads, they do not map 1-1. https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#goroutines

Comment: you can read more about goroutines in this [blog](https://golangbot.com/goroutines/). goroutines is lightweight thread, which is not an actual OS thread. If a goroutine is blocked (by IO, e.g. waiting for user input), the runtime will start a new OS thread and move other goroutines to the new OS thread.

Comment: "How does Go do this without goroutine switching?" It doesn't. It switches several goroutines (your main, the spinner and several used for GC) to the one available OS thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Among others : the compiler inserts potential switch points at each function call, so each recursive call to `fib(...)` can yield to the "spinner" goroutine.

If you try to implement fib without any function call for example :

```
// note : this is a truly horrific way to compute the Fibonacci sequence,
//        don't do this at home
// simulate the "compute Fibonacci recursively" algorithm,
// but without any function call
func fib(n int) int {
    var res = 0

    var stack []int
    stack = append(stack, n)

    for len(stack) > 0 {
        // pop :
        n = stack[len(stack)-1]
        stack = stack[0 : len(stack)-1]

        if n < 2 {
            res += n
            continue
        }

        // else : push 'n-1' and 'n-2' on the stack
        stack = append(stack, n-1, n-2)
    }

    return res
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/pdoAaBwyscr

you should see your spinner 'stuck'

Comment: On the other hand, there's no guarantee that it *will* yield at such points. It's a matter of luck, sort of. (It's *predictable* by inspecting the compiled code and runtime libraries, but that code and the libraries might change from one Go release to another.)

Comment: @torek: yes, this was skillfully suggested behind the "*can* yield" ;)  I went looking for a good reference about the go scheduler, and how the compiler inserted scheduling points, but I wasn't able to find the article I remembered reading on the subject